# java ubuntu add to upper panel

Tags: java, ubuntu

Hi i want to write program which i can add to upper panel in ubuntu, the program will be do:

- check connection to my server check
- if checksum of file change if it
- change will show a cloud with last
  line from file

Is it posible to add write such program in JAVA.
I found this http://znasibov.info/blog/post/gnome-applet-with-python-part-1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 6 supports access to the system tray (which I believe is the upper panel in Ubuntu) so have a look at https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/systemtray.html which shows screen dumps of the various operating system trays.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html for a sample program.

I've found that the timing between successive balloons is different between operating systems.

Comment: Link is great but I can set icon on panel i get gray rectangle (i've cope code from secound link) EDIT: Problem solver I had to use `trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);`

Comment: are you certain you actually have an image loaded when setting the icon?

Comment: Yes file exists. Solution was in `trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);`

Comment: One more question in this subject. Is it possible to add action for close message from `tray.displayMessage()` ??

Comment: I don't know.  You may want to open a new question for this.